# install an engenius usb wifi adapter in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wireless, usb

My understanding was that 18.04 would "see" my Engenius USB wifi adapter and it would work, as the driver is in the kernel.  The system does not see the adapter and I don't know how install the driver provided for linux by the manufacturer.  I am pretty much and novice at command line.  Any help would be appreciated.